# Who is the father of CIL?

Tags: .net, history

...formerly known as MSIL, simple question, it is widely known that Anders Hejlsberg is the father of C#, but is there a "father of CIL"?

Comment: I bet it's Anders as well, I bet he probably gets around a lot.  ...that, and CIL has his nose! ;)

Comment: Things like C# and CIL are *spawned*, not born, so there is no real "father", only "the demon who bears the blame."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CIL was not really the creation of a single individual, but was the result of the efforts of a team of many, accompanied by Microsoft's already substantial existing compiler and execution engine assets and experience.

Some of the key drivers and contributors of the CIL include Anders Hejlsberg, Jim Miller, Erik Meijer, Brad Lovering, Maoni Stephens, Patrick Dussud. There are many others who I'm forgetting.

Several non-MSFT specialists including Don Box (now @ Microsoft), Jeff Richter, John Gough, and others contributed greatly to the design and the implementation of the CLI, as did the ECMA standardization reviewers and contributors.

Answer (score 0):

The main person behind MSIL was **Vance Morrison**.

Of course, **Patrick Dussud** was there too and probably an important contributor.

Source: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Vance-Morrison-CLR-Through-the-Years